# Calculate the residue of $\frac{e^{2z}}{(e^{iz} +1)}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to calculate the residue of $\text{res}_{z=\pi}\dfrac{e^{2z}}{(e^{iz} +1)}$
The expected answer is $\dfrac{e^{2z}}{(1-i)}$. Im getting $\dfrac{e^{2z}}{(-i)}$ as the answer.

Comment: A residue is a _number_, not a function...

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex). I tried to improve your post using TeX (for better readability). Please check whether these edits did not unintentionally change the meaning of your post.

Comment: If you plug in $z=\pi$, you get $ie^{2\pi}$, which is the correct residue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the denominator $g(z)=e^{iz}-1$ has a simple zero at $z_0=\pi$, and numerator $f(z)=e^{2z}$ never vanishes, you can apply the following formula
$$\operatorname{Res}\Big(\frac{f}{g},z_0\Big)=\frac{f(z_0)}{g'(z_0)}$$
giving in your case the following result
$$\operatorname{Res}\Big(\frac{e^{2z}}{e^{iz}+1},\pi\Big)=\frac{e^{2\pi}}{ie^{i\pi}}=\frac{e^{2\pi}}{-i}=e^{2\pi}i$$

Comment: Thanks for the help..my lecture notes has the wrong answer

Comment: @Federica Maggioni, writes, "Since the denominator ... has a simple pole..." This matter is elucidated nicely here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2945768/residue-fz-fracezez-1?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

The pole is simple, thus

$$\text{res}_{z=\pi }(f)=\lim_{z\to \pi }(z-\pi )\frac{e^{2z}}{e^{iz}+1}\stackrel{\text{l'Hospital, for ex.}}=\frac{e^{2\pi }}{ie^{i\pi }}=\frac{e^{2\pi}}{-i}=ie^{2\pi} $$

Comment: residue at $\pi$, not $\pi i$

Comment: $$
\lim_{z\to\pi}\frac{e^{2z}(z-\pi)}{e^{iz}+1}=\frac{e^{2\pi}}{ie^{i\pi}}=ie^{2\pi}
$$

Comment: Thanks @FedericaMaggioni, completely forgot when calculating all that thing.

Comment: Indeed @robjohn, took the wrong limit. Thanks.

Comment: @DonAntonioi, writes, "The pole is simple," This matter is elucidated nicely here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2945768/residue-fz-fracezez-1?rq=1